# should I use the preposition "in"

Tags: prepositions

Should "in" be used in this ex: I am interested **in** working abroad or I am interested working abroad. Or both are correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

> I am interested **in** working abroad.

When you omit the *in*, you are "interested" and you are "working abroad", but there is no relationship between them. So conceptually *in* is necessary.

In this example, the phrase is *interest in*. See [*interest*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/138177/should-i-use-the-preposition-in/138179#138179):

> 1. *variable noun*
>      If you have an interest in something, you want to learn or hear more about it.

While in some cases prepositions can be omitted, *in* is not a preposition in your example.